# Stanza Stanford NLP: cannot import name 'StanzaLanguage' from 'spacy_stanza'

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm getting the following error when importing StanzaLanguage from spacy_stanza:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
4 import stanza
5 stanza.download('es')
----> 6 from spacy_stanza import StanzaLanguage
7
8

ImportError: cannot import name 'StanzaLanguage' from 'spacy_stanza' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spacy_stanza/**init**.py)

Answer (score 2):

I think you've installed newest spacy-stanza but you're trying to use it with older spaCy:

```
As of v1.0.0 spacy-stanza is only compatible with spaCy v3.x. For spaCy v2, install v0.2.x
```

```
pip install "spacy-stanza<0.3.0"
```

Take a look what are the differences in `Usage & Examples` between them:
https://github.com/explosion/spacy-stanza vs https://github.com/explosion/spacy-stanza/tree/v0.2.x#-usage--examples